# Local Authentication Succeeds with Any Non-Empty Passcode on Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, touch-id

*(Related to [this (a bit outdated) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459059/is-there-any-way-to-use-apples-touch-id-fingerprint-scanner-on-ios-simulator), but not the same.)*

#### Background

Xcode 7.2, iOS 9.2. I am updating some local authentication/keychain demo projects I did back then, to Swift 2.

I put the code below together and tested it on the simulator:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    var error: NSError?

    let context = LAContext()
    
    
    guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) else {
        print("Can not evaluate policy")
        return
    }
    
    context.evaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthentication,
        localizedReason: "Authenticate!",
        reply: { (success, error) -> Void in
            
            if success {
                print("SUCCESS")
            }
            else{
                switch LAError(rawValue: error!.code)! {
                case .AuthenticationFailed:
                    break
                case .UserCancel:
                    break
                case .UserFallback:
                    break
                case .SystemCancel:
                    break
                case .PasscodeNotSet:
                    break
                case .TouchIDNotEnrolled:
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

To my surprise, when I run this code on the "iPhone 5" or "iPhone 5s" simulators, the "Alphanumeric passcode" screen appears:

[image]

(*there is no "Touch ID & Passcode" section in Settings.app for the simulator. Also, "Touch ID Enrolled" is **unchecked** in the Simulator's OSX menu*)

If I tap the **Cancel** button (i.e., the "return" button while the password field is empty), authentication fails as expected (execution jumps to `case .UserCancel:` in the code above).

But if I type anything, the **Cancel** button will change to **Done**, and tapping it will cause authentication to succeed.

*(If I enable `Hardware > Touch ID Enrolled`, the `Simulate Finger Touch >` works as expected.)*

#### Questions:

- Is there a way (that I'm missing) to set a **specific passcode**, and check against that? (instead of "anything passes validation")
- Is there a way to choose 4-digit passcode, 6-digit passcode, etc. instead of the complex password format I'm seeing now?

Comment: You might want to check the documentation regarding this with simulator. It might just be some heuristic with simulator to emulate a real phone and if you run it on a real phone it might work the way you expect it.

Comment: Yes, it does run as expected on the device.

Comment: Well, if it runs as expected on the device, then you should be fine. I guess it's because the simulator doesn't really have an operating system - I think it's just emulates part of the OS.

Comment: I know... it's just weird that the simulator accepts any password.

Comment: So how do you test the "failed password" case?

Comment: @PaulCezanne on the device, I guess. The simulator seems to take any non-empty password.